# Como realizar la conexión al web servicie frecuencia / cotizador de ESTAFETA

Tags: php, webservice, api

Soy principiante en los temas relacionados a las APIS y web services, en este caso estoy realizando el web service para el apartado de frecuencia / cotizador de la paqueteria ESTAFETA con PHP, esto con el fin de incrustarlo en mi ecommerce.
Entiendo la estructura del (xml) los parametros que conlleva, mas no se como realizar la conexion a la url de producción que proporcionan.

la url que corresponde a producción es la siguiente: http://frecuenciacotizador.estafeta.com/Service.asmx

y el xml de ejemplo de petición al web service:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:est="http://www.estafeta.com/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<est:FrecuenciaCotizador>
<est:idusuario>1</est:idusuario>
<!--Optional:-->
<est:usuario>User</est:usuario>
<!--Optional:-->
<est:contra>password</est:contra>
<est:esFrecuencia>true</est:esFrecuencia>  Solo Frecuencia
<est:esLista>true</est:esLista> El código postal origen y destino pueden
<!--Optional:--> ser Uno o Varios Códigos postales.
<est:tipoEnvio>
<est:EsPaquete>false</est:EsPaquete> El tipo de envío es Sobre
<est:Largo>0</est:Largo> Los parametros largo, peso, alto y ancho
<est:Peso>0</est:Peso> no serán tomados en cuenta ya que el
<est:Alto>0</est:Alto> tipo de envío es Sobre
<est:Ancho>0</est:Ancho>
</est:tipoEnvio>
<!--Optional:-->
<est:datosOrigen>
<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
<est:string>01000</est:string> Código Postal Origen
</est:datosOrigen>
<!--Optional:-->
<est:datosDestino>
<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
<est:string>62000</est:string> Código Postal Destino
</est:datosDestino>
</est:FrecuenciaCotizador>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Podria alguien orientarme un poco acerca del tema?

Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. La URL que proporcionas no devuelve un XML. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer en sí, consultar una URL que devuelve un XML, recibirlo y leerlo? Falta claridad en tu pregunta y elementos que muestren el estado real del problema.